# Installing Spark Cluster

Tags: 14.04, openstack, cluster

I am following this tutorial to install spark cluster. 
http://arnesund.com/2015/09/21/spark-cluster-on-openstack-with-multi-user-jupyter-notebook/

I am manually copy pasting all the commands as I faced couple of issues using cloud-init.

> I am not able to run following commands from the tutorial:

**Download and unpack Spark**

```
 curl -o /tmp/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1.tgz http://$APACHE_MIRROR/spark/spark-$SPARK_VERSION/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1.tgz
 tar xvz -C /opt -f /tmp/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1.tgz
 ln -s /opt/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1/ /opt/spark
 chown -R root.root /opt/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1/*
```

You can have a look at these commands from the above mentioned link.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ubuntu@sparkmaster:~$ curl -o /tmp/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1.tgz http://$APACHE_MIRROR/spark/spark-$SPARK_VERSION/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop1.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SPARK_VERSION`, `$APACHE_MIRROR` are [environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) so just copy pasting as individual commands won't work.

The tutorial you've pointed above is about setting up a Spark cluster on OpenStack VMs.

First write a [bash script](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) as shown in in the tutorial. (init-spark-master.sh)

Then just executing it will do.

**UPDATE--**

Unless you set the environment variables beforehand, you should execute complete commands.

For example,
`curl -o /tmp/spark-apache.uib.no-bin-hadoop1.tgz http://apache.uib.no/spark/spark-1.5.0/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop1.tgz`
would run without any problem.

Comment: I am using a private cloud provided by my institute, and it is based on OpenStack. I have already started the VM manually that's why I am running the commands. Bash script would be useful if I use openstack nova api and source the bash script.

Comment: `curl -o /tmp/spark-$SPARK_VERSION...` would never work unless you set the $SPARK_VERSION beforehand.